# Go back in multiple pages form

Tags: php, forms, session

I am currently building a multiple pages form using `$_SESSION`, everything has been working fine so far. Yet, even though I am able to retrieve all the data at the end of the 6 pages, it seems that it is not possible to go back in the form if the user made a mistake.

Let's say he is at page 5 and he realizes that he needs to go back to page 3 to change something, he won't be able to do so. Firefox gives this error message :

*Document Expired
This document is no longer available.
The requested document is not available in Firefox's cache.As a security precaution, Firefox does not automatically re-request sensitive documents.Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website.*

This is what my forms look like, this one is Form-1.php :

```
<form action="Form-2.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                    <input id="age" type="number" name="age" placeholder="Ex. 1988" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input id="sex-m" type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" required/>
                    <label for="sex-m">Male</label>
                    <input id="sex-f" type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" required/>
                    <label for="sex-f">Female</label>
                </p>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Next page"/>
</form>
```

I am using `SESSION` to retrieve data from the previous form, this one is from Form-2.php :

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
$_SESSION['sex'] = $_POST['sex'];
```

And so on for the six pages.

It works fine, it retrieves all the values correctly, but it is not possible to go back when filling the form.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure the user will be able to go back if he makes a mistake?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

I ended up with the following code, solving half of my problem. Still from Form-2.php :

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['location']) && isset($_SESSION['job'])) {
        $location = $_SESSION['location'];
        $job = $_SESSION['job'];
} else {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
        $_SESSION['sex'] = $_POST['sex'];

        $location = '';
        $job = '';
}
```

Then I simply display the values in the fields with :

If text : `<?php echo $location; ?>`

If radio : `<?php if(isset($job) && $job == "Yes"){echo "checked=\"checked\" ";} ?>`

It works quite well, the different forms - if the values have been set - are pre-populated just fine.

My problem is, as you can see, if I go back and **change** a value, it won't be taken into consideration as I am ignoring `POST` if there is a corresponding value stored in `SESSION`.

I can't figure out how to make this work properly... Any hint?

Comment: Fyi, the english word "Informations" does not exist. It's always "Information".

Comment: True, I translated my form quickly and I missed this one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but does the job: Do not use back buttons, provide your own forward, backwards, "step" buttons. Then populate the form with the data stored in e.g. the session.

Comment: I am already using such a button : `<input type="submit" value="Next page"/>`. Backward button could be fine, how can I implement it without messing my data up though?

Comment: Well, not so easy. You have to find your own way to handle all the post, session (+validating, +db_data_format) data. I use some kind of form2session, session2form, session2db + validation class to handle all that.

Comment: I see, could you show me an example, or a piece of code that would help me get started? This form is a little specific, it does not require any SQL request or anything, I simply need to gather the data and assemble it.

Comment: If the form field data and the expected data is the same (so 1=1 and not 1 = "yes") you just set $_SESSION = $_POST ... but as you see, this is not that easy. So you need to code some kind of form handler, getting and setting your data.

Comment: Thanks ! I came up with a solution (see edit) but there still is a problem I can't figure out. Any hint?

Comment: @morgi: So you know what to do: Set all relevant POST to the SESSION on submit - e.g. $_SESSION['userdata'] = $_POST. On other pages, if submit is not pressed (=POST empty), do it the other way round - get the data from the session. $_POST =$_SESSION['userdata'] ... an do not forget to let the user "clear" things, So e.g. unset($_SESSION['userdata']['sex']) if the user clears this form field.

Comment: @morgi: Perhaps it is easier for you to have all form fields in all pages. Then only the ones needed are shown as form fields, all others are hidden inputs. This way you would not have to fiddle around with the session'to'post thing. But then you will have to make sure, every "link" fires up a POST-request (here: at least your back and forward buttons/links).

Comment: @morgi: If you stick to the session-post thing, make it as flexible, that you can use it for other related tasks, like last search, or paging (with last search query) ... and if you come up to something handy, write a comment - I could use sth like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

djot is right, you need a << back >> and << forward >> button, what you can do in functionality is if back button is clicked pass the values of the page/form as hidden input fields and populate the fields using the values in the hidden..